# Rewrite URLs to redirect and drop leading zero

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, bluehost

I have two blogs on two different domains that I am consolidating onto one site. I'm not too familiar with server admin, but I'm 99% sure what I want to do is possible on bluehost (since they allow .htaccess) and using mod_rewrite (or similar.)

Currently I have `blog1.com` and `blog2.com` and post urls looks like `blog1.com/001` and `blog2.com/030`. What I want is for anyone who enters one of those URLs to be redirected to `example.com/blog1/1` and `example.com/blog2/30`

That means I need to:

1. Redirect the entire domain to a folder on my new domain
2. Redirect hits to the URL with leading zeroes to URLs without leading zeroes
3. This probably means redirecting `blog1.com/001` *and* `example.com/blog1/001` to `example.com/blog1/1`

**UPDATED**

On http://htaccess.madewithlove.be 1st & 2nd condition met but rules don't fire.

3rd totally breaks and returns weirdness: `http://example.com/blog1/030log1/030`

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect blog1.com/030 => example.com/blog1/30
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(blog1|blog2)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9]+)/?$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect example.com/blog1/030 => example.com/blog1/30
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog1|blog2)/0*([1-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [NC,R=301,L]

# Never use www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(([a-z0-9_]+.)?example.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `blog1` and `blog2` domains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(blog1|blog2)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^0*([1-9]+)/?$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L]

# rule2 for example.com/blog1/030 => example.com/blog1/30
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog1|blog2)/0+([1-9]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [NC,R=302,L]
```

- `%1` is back-reference to `blog1` or `blog2` in `RewriteCond`
- `^0*([1-9]+)` will match all leading zeroes leaving only non-zero numbers in `$1`

Comment: Well that seems simple enough. Thanks so much for explaining it too. Are the vanilla regex rules? A subset? Superset?

Comment: I'm testing this on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and the rule works (awesome, thank you!) but `example.com/a/030` doesn't redirect to `example.com/a/30` as expected. Will that need to be it's own Cond/Rule?

Comment: But what is `/a/` directory. This rule take host name part from `RewriteCond` and there is no `a` there in new request.

Comment: Sorry I did that thing where you mixup your examples and confuse the people trying to help you. What I _meant_ was: `example.com/blog1/030` doesn't redirect to `example.com/blog1/30` as expected. Will that need to be it's own Cond/Rule?

Comment: 1. Never post code in comments, no one can read it. 2. Never test on that site, it is unreliable 3. Clearly tell for which URL it doesn't work

Comment: I thought I deleted that comment after I saw how god awfully it was formatted. It's gone now. I updated my question above with what I was trying to fit in the comment. If I can't test there do you have another recommendation?

Comment: Better to test on your local web server. I made a minor edit and it worked  fine for all the conditions on my Apache.